# Recreating brace diagram with schemata or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, schemata

It's the first time drawing graphics in LaTeX and I'm trying to recreate a diagram published in a book, that needs to be faithful to the original:
[image: Souriau]

I've approached it with `schemata`, and it's not quite there yet:
[image]

Braces are not aligned or the same size as in the original. I've tried using `\\quad` and `\hspace` to displace the braces, but they went too far to the right regardless of the value.

Feedback welcome!

- I'd accept suggestions in `tikz` if you also solve it with `schemata`.
- The original diagram is not ideal and here there are people with a lot of experience, so I'm curious what would you do to better convey this idea, if you could start from scratch. Do what feels right, go wild.

English source:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{schemata}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
  \bgroup\footnotesize\begin{center}
  \Schema{-1.4ex}{12ex}
  { \schemabox{Representational\\ Art (2nd grade)} }
  {
    \Schema{0ex}{3.5ex}
      { \NudgeSB\schemabox{} }
      { \Schema[close]{0ex}{3.5ex}
        { \NudgeSB\schemabox{Art that represents material objects\\
          as they appear in concrete perception} }
        { \NudgeSB\schemabox{Figurative Art} }
      }
      \Schema{2ex}{8ex}
        { \schemabox{Abstract Art (in\\ proper sense)} }
        {
          \Schema{-4ex}{3.5ex}
            { \schemabox{Art that evokes isolated\\ elements from its original object\\ and considers them separately} }
            {
              \Schema[close]{-4.4ex}{3.5ex}
                { \schemabox{perceptive\\ affective\\ intellectual} }
                { \Schema[close]{2ex}{8ex} { }
                    { \schemabox{Abstract Art (in\\ proper sense)} } }
            }
        }
  }
  \Schema{0ex}{6ex}
    { \schemabox{Non-representa-\\tional Art \\
      (1\textsuperscript{st} grade)} }
    {
      \Schema[close]{0ex}{9ex}
        { \schemabox{Art whose works have an\\ intrinsic organization and\\ do not overlay other\\ organizations of sensations\\ intended to represent something}  }
        { \schemabox{Non-figurative Art\\ incorrectly called\\ abstract} }
    }
  \end{center}\egroup\smallskip
\end{document}
```

Note: The diagram comes from Étienne Souriau's *Vocabulaire d'esthétique*, I'm using a Spanish translation.

Comment: Personal opinion: I don't like the braces. Some are bigger than what they embrace. It isn't really clear what they mean. Is this some kind of mindmap/Venn graph? That said, a little bit of `matrix` library (for the delimiters could also be brace decoration), a bit of `fit` and the proper order of statements and you could do this with TikZ. There's probably also a `nicematrix` solution possible. Will be totally different input syntax, though.

Comment: Yea I totally get where you're coming from. As I understand, the author was trying to convey how _abstract art_ did't work trying to mirror reality, and how the term _abstract art_ was used incorrectly to refer to all non-figurative art.

Regarding `matrix`, `fit` and `tikz`; how to combine them the way you're suggesting?

Answer (score 3):

A rough solution using the `nicematrix` package (which omits two braces which I think are superfluous):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\noindent\footnotesize\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ 
    *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}} 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12em}
    *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}} 
}
\Block[l]{5-1}{Representational Art (2nd grade)} 
    & \Block[l]{1-4}{Art that represents material objects \\ as they appear in concrete perception}
    &
    &
    &
    & Figurative Art \\
    & \Block[l]{3-1}{Abstract Art (in proper sense)}
    & \Block[l]{2-1}{Art that evokes isolated elements from its original object and considers them separately}
    & perceptive affective intellectual 
    & \Block[l]{3-1}{Abstract Art (in proper sense)}
    & \Block[l]{5-1}{Non-figurative Art incorrectly called abstract} \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
Non-represen\-tational Art 
    & \Block[l]{1-4}{Art whose works have an intrinsic organization and\\ do not overlay other organizations of sensations \\ intended to represent something} 
    & & & & \\
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix\{{1-2}{5-2}.
    \SubMatrix.{1-5}{1-5}\}
    \SubMatrix\{{2-3}{4-3}.
    \SubMatrix\{{2-4}{3-4}.
    \SubMatrix.{2-4}{4-4}\}
    \SubMatrix\{{6-2}{6-2}.
    \SubMatrix.{2-5}{6-5}\}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For fine-grained control you could also switch to Ti*k*Z to draw the braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\tikzset{
    brace/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace}
    },
    ecarb/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\footnotesize\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ 
    *{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}} 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12em}
    *{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}} 
}
\Block[l]{5-1}{Representational Art (2nd grade)} 
    & \Block[l]{1-4}{Art that represents material objects \\ as they appear in concrete perception}
    &
    &
    &
    & Figurative Art \\
    & \Block[l]{3-1}{Abstract Art (in proper sense)}
    & \Block[l]{2-1}{Art that evokes isolated elements from its original object and considers them separately}
    & perceptive affective intellectual 
    & \Block[l]{3-1}{Abstract Art (in proper sense)}
    & \Block[l]{5-1}{Non-figurative Art incorrectly called abstract} \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
\vspace*{2em}
    & & & & & \\
Non-represen\-tational Art 
    & \Block[l]{1-4}{Art whose works have an intrinsic organization and\\ do not overlay other organizations of sensations \\ intended to represent something} 
    & & & & \\
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ecarb] ([yshift=-2pt]1 -| 2) -- ([yshift=2pt]6 -| 2);
        \draw[ecarb] ([yshift=-2pt]6 -| 2) -- ([yshift=2pt]7 -| 2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, is it possible to add spacing between the braces so they breathe a bit more?

Comment: @Neveda You could try adding empty rows and/or change the row height using something like `\\[10pt]` instead of the regular `\\ `. Or you could use Ti*k*Z to draw the braces as shown in the edit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! As of now the closest I got to being faithful to the original is using `schemata` and failed with the others, will try to give it another spin when I have a moment.